# What is the appropriate use of the Article element?

Tags: html

I want to change

```
<section>
  <header>...</header>
  <p class="tweet">This is a tweet preview. You can... <em>6 Hours ago</em></p>
</section>
```

into

```
<section>
  <header>...</header>
  <article class="tweet">
    <p>This is a tweet preview. You can... <time pubdate>6 Hours ago</time></p>
  </article>
</section>
```

But after reading some [articles](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) on the `<article>` tag, I'm not sure that this is the best move. What would be better practice?

Comment: Would a "tweet" really constitute as an [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/article)?

Comment: Reading articles on the article tag?  That's meta.

Comment: @Brad Christie It all depends. If that's the main content of the site, then yes. However, if it's just a small add-on then an `aside` may be better suited.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you propose a case where a tweet _is_ the main content of the site, aside from twitter.com itself?

Comment: ["It is often confused with section and div but don’t worry we’ll explain the difference"](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) The usage of the `<article>` depends on the contents meaning.

Comment: @Brad Christie A poor example, but I have a tumblr site that updates using my tweets as posts. I also add regular text posts to it, but the tweets act as a sort of 'main' content, at least enough to warrant the tag. Again, the whole argument is rather subjective. A tweet would've been wrapped in a `div` in the past, the new tags are just more things to wrap content with.

Comment: Andrew Peacock - I feel like a twitter feed wouldn't fit in an `<aside>` within a `<section>` because all `<aside>` sections semantically needs to be related to the content within their section.

Comment: while these tags do indeed add to the semantic meaning, it still feels like some esoteric spec gobbledygook. Just use a div; your users won't care, and we won't have to discuss its meaning ad nauseam.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The important thing to understand about articles and sections is that they are sectioning elements. Each follows a common pattern:

```
<sectioning_element>
    <heading_or_header>
    ... the body text and markup of the section
    <footer>
</sectioning_element>
```

The footer is optional. Sectioning elements should have a "natural" heading. That is, it should be easy to write an `<h?>` element at the start of the section/article, that describes and summarises the entire content of the section/article, such that other things on the page not inside the section/article would not be described by the heading.

It's not necessary to explicitly include the natural heading on the page, if for example, it was self evident what the heading would be and for stylistic reasons you didn't want to display it, but you should be able to say easily what it would have been had you chosen to include it.*

For example, a section might have a natural heading "cars for sale". It's extremely likely that from the content contained within the section, it would be patently obvious that the section was about cars being for sale, and that including the heading would be redundant information.

`<section>` tends to be used for grouping things. Their natural headers are typically plural. e.g. "Cars for Sale"

`<article>` is for units of content. Their natural headers are usually a title for the whole of the text that follows. e.g. "My New Car"

So, if you're not grouping some things, then there's no need, and it's not correct, to use another sectioning element in between the header and footer of the section and your correct mark-up would be

```
<article class="tweet">
  <header>...</header>
  <p>This is a tweet preview. You can... <em>6 Hours ago</em></p>
</article>
```

assuming you can find a natural heading to go inside the `<header>` element. If you can't, then the correct mark-up is simply

```
<p class="tweet">This is a tweet preview. You can... <em>6 Hours ago</em></p>
```

or

```
<div class="tweet">
     <p>This is a tweet preview. You can... <em>6 Hours ago</em></p>
</div>
```

---

* There's a case for including the natural heading anyway, and making it "display:none". Doing so will allow the section/article to be referenced cleanly by the document outline.

Answer (score 11):

`<article>` content

> represents a self-contained composition in a document, page,
>   application, or site and that is, in principle, independently
>   distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum
>   post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted
>   comment, **an interactive widget or gadget**, or any other independent
>   item of content.

([from the html5 working spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element))

in fact one of the examples illustrates nested `<article>` elements where the inner `<article>` is inside a `<section>`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you think it's a good move? It seems to me that a Tweet would fit perfectly in the W3C spec on what should be in an article. It would most likely depend on the context your sample code is in (which we can't tell from what you've provided).

[It could also be put this way.](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2010/on-html5-article-element/)

Answer (score 0):

The semantics don't matter THAT much. You could very well do that if you wanted to and it would be fine. The thing with the `article` vs. `section` usage debate is that it's all subjective, to a point. I would recommend against how you're doing it in the second version though because it seems as though that just clutters the code more. What you could do is just replace the `section` tag with an `article` tag.

Comment: Since the <article> tag can contain a <header> tag, it stands to reason that you can do away with the sections in this example and simply have articles. Sections would be for grouping articles together, if that's something you need to do.

Comment: `section` tags can also be meant for various sections of the site. If the `section` contains quite a few tweets then it would be okay to use it. However, if each tweet is wrapped in a `section` then I would definitely not suggest the second option because that would lead to extremely bloated code.

Comment: @Andrew - Agreed. From the spec, it would seem to me that using `<article>` for Tweets is almost a textbook example (aside from...well...articles), as long as it's something like `<section><article class="tweet"></article><article class="tweet"></article><article class="tweet"></article></section>`

Comment: @Shauna Exactly. I don't follow the spec to the T though. I find some of it a bit limiting and often times confusing trying to figure out what would go where and be 100% correct. Instead I go by feel because it's faster and less frustrating. Look what happened with tables, they were used to layout entire websites. This is a huge upgrade semantically from that, so even if the uses aren't always completely correct, it's better than using tables.

Answer (score -1):

I went through quite a bit of head scratching to understand it because it seems to be confusing to quite a few but it really should be looked at a bit more literally. Here is an easy way to look at it:

Sections can contain elements from different topics.
Articles should contain elements from the same topic.

For example:

```
<section>
    <section>
        <article id="article_ONE">
            <header>...</header>
            <p>Not directly related to article_TWO</p>
            <footer>...</footer>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article id="article_TWO">
            <article>
                <header>...</header>
                <p>Part 1 of article TWO</p>
                <footer>...</footer>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>...</header>
                <p>Part 2 of article TWO</p>
                <footer>...</footer>
            </article>
        </article>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: “Sections can contain elements from different topics. Articles should contain elements from the same topic.” — Eh? Where did you get that from?

Comment: Both your article tags have the same id?

Comment: Paul, I used "topic" as an analogy instead of "self-contained composition".

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element